# How to fix VStudio 2022 not centering code files in well, but hiding them minimized far left (possibly docked elsewhere)

Tags: visual-studio-2022

My VS2022 went mad this morning.
Instead of opening codefiles in the center (the 'well'), they are opened minimized and un-resizable in some far left edge / container of the 'well'

[image]

Comment: Do you get the same if you create a brand new solution? If not then something may have got corrupted, try deleting the .vs folder (in the root of your problematic solution folder). If no luck then you could try resetting all your Visual Studio settings. I assume you've already tried turning it off and on again? ;)

Comment: I get the same with a new project.
There is no .vs folder in the solutions folder